# Silverlight VisualStateManager list of states

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I know I've seen a list before of the predefined VisualStateGroups and states for a VisualStateManager, including CommonStates, CheckedStates, etc., but I can't seem to find it again.

Does anyone know where such a list might be found?

**EDIT:**

I'm catching on to the fact that lots of these obvious reference lists are built in to Expression Blend, which Microsoft apparently assumes everyone will buy.  That or they hope that by not making this stuff easy to find, we'll cough up the money and buy the thing out of sheer frustration.

I'm a contractor for the federal government, and we've ordered EB, but of course it will take months for the order to get approved and processed and delivered.  In the mean time, my trial download has long since expired and I'm stuck here in hand-coding land (where I honestly would prefer to stay).  In the mean time, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recall coming across any list of "predefined" groups.  However the place where you can find lists of groups in close proximty is in the [Control Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc278075(VS.95).aspx) documentation.  But for general reference the list of Groups shared by multiple controls found here are:-

- CommonStates
- FocusStates
- PopupStates
- ValidationStates
- CheckStates

Bizarely `RadioButton` has a group called `CheckedStates` not `CheckStates`.  Basically the group names really only have meaning within the control so its not technically that important what they are called.  However it certainly would makes sense to re-use group names that describe a common domain of states.